# After trying to get ubuntu 13.10 to recognize windows 8 install windows 8 won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I was trying to dual boot Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8 using a LiveUSB but when attempting to install Ubuntu, it didn't recognize my Windows 8 install.

I did a couple things trying to get it to recognize it from [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240913/ubuntu-liveusb-doesnt-recognize-my-windows-8-installation) and also [tried zapping GPT structures](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/02/26/zap-gpt-data-structures-from-a-disk-while-preserving-existing-mbr-partitions/) as well. I believe when I zapped the GPT structures, bad things happened.

Now Windows 8 will not boot but says it needs to be repaired. It references the winload.efi file missing or something.

I tried making a Windows recovery USB, but it is unable to refresh because the drive is locked, and it will not reset because `a required drive partition is missing`.

I never ended up going through with the Ubuntu install just to make sure everything else stayed put. I can see all my old files and all the old partitions are still there.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please run GParted in Ubuntu and post a screenshot of the partitions (through a link to dropbox or something)?

Answer (score 0):

Zapping the GPT data structures was almost certainly a mistake. The reference to `winload.efi` makes me think you had an EFI-booting Windows installation. If your computer came with Windows 8 pre-installed, this is further evidence of an EFI-bootable Windows. Such an installation would require GPT, so by zapping the GPT data, you've erased your partition information.

If this hypothesis is correct, your best bet is to use a tool like [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover your partitions. That said, posting your partition information (what you get when you type `sudo parted /dev/sda print` or `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` in an Ubuntu Terminal window) will give more information about the current state of your disk. It's conceivable that something less radical and risky than using TestDisk will fix the problem.